# how to update the ruby hash based on values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have following input

```
a = {"Mar-14"=>"440", "Jan-14"=>"-1958190", "Feb-14"=>"-1634613", "Apr"=>"100"}
```

I want output like this

```
positive = {"Mar-14"=>"440","Apr"=>"100"}
negative = {"Jan-14"=>"-1958190", "Feb-14"=>"-1634613"}
```

How to get this done?

Note:output format need to  be hash

Comment: What is the logic behind it? What happens if the value is `"0"`? Don't be lazy.

Comment: check here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-each and the doc in general. Your problem is much simpler than you might think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Hash#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) would work:

```
negative = a.select { |k, v| v.to_i < 0 }
#=> {"Jan-14"=>"-1958190", "Feb-14"=>"-1634613"}

positive = a.select { |k, v| v.to_i >= 0 }
#=> {"Mar-14"=>"440", "Apr"=>"100"}
```

There's also [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) but it returns an array so you'll have to re-map it:

```
negative, positive = a.partition { |k, v| v.to_i < 0 }.map(&:to_h)
```